# Statefull widget not changing data, how to fix that?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a text field which get its part of data from a function(getCurrentAssetsData), which gets data from a database(sqlite).

```
title: Text(this.coins[position].coin.toString() + " Temp Data " + getCurrentAssetsData(this.coins[position]).toString()),
```

But it showing **null** instead of the data.
The data is coming correctly as I am able to print statements.
[image: null value]

My code:

```
class CoinList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CoinListState createState() => _CoinListState();
}

class _CoinListState extends State<CoinList> {
  DbHelper helper = DbHelper();
  List<Coin> coins;
  int count=0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(coins==null){
      coins = List<Coin>();
      getData();
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: coinListItems(),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          navigateToDetail(Coin(0,''));
        },
        tooltip: "Add new Todo",
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
  ListView coinListItems(){
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: count,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int position){
        return GestureDetector(
          child: SwipeDetector(
            child:Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 2.0,
            child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                child: Text(this.coins[position].id.toString()),
              ),
              title: Text(this.coins[position].coin.toString() + " Temp Data " + getCurrentAssetsData(this.coins[position]).toString()), //title
              subtitle: Text(this.coins[position].description),

              onTap: (){
                //TODO:Open Coin specific orders
                navigateToOrders(this.coins[position]);
              },

            ),
          ),
            onSwipeRight: () {
              print("Swipe Right");//TODO:Delete coin code
            },
          ),
          onDoubleTap: (){
        debugPrint("Tapped on "+this.coins[position].id.toString());
        navigateToDetail(this.coins[position]);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
  void getData(){
    final dbFuture = helper.initializeDb();
    dbFuture.then((result){
      final coinFuture = helper.getCoin();
      coinFuture.then(
              (result){
            List<Coin> coins = List<Coin>();
            count = result.length;
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
              coins.add(Coin.fromObject(result[i]));
              debugPrint(coins[i].marketValue.toString());//title
            }
            setState(() {
              this.coins = coins;
              count = count;
            });
            debugPrint("Items "+count.toString());
          }
      );
    });
  }

  String getCurrentAssetsData(coin){

    final dbFuture = helper.initializeDb();
    dbFuture.then((result){
      //final coin = helper.retrieveCoin(coin_name);
      final coinOrderFuture = helper.getCoinOrder(coin);
      double totalCost = 0;
      double totalCount = 0;
      double totalCommission=0;
      coinOrderFuture.then(
              (result){
            List<CoinOrder> coinOrders = List<CoinOrder>();
            int count = result.length;
            for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
              coinOrders.add(CoinOrder.fromObject(result[i]));
              totalCost += coinOrders[i].count * coinOrders[i].buyValue;
              totalCount += coinOrders[i].count;
              totalCommission+= coinOrders[i].commission;
            }

            //averagePrice = totalCost/totalCount;
            //totalCommission = totalCommission;
            //totalCost = totalCost;
            String sData = "Avg: ${totalCost/totalCount} Investment: ${totalCost}";
            debugPrint(sData);
            return sData;

          }
      );
    });
  }

  void navigateToDetail(Coin coin) async{
    bool result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>CoinDetail(coin)),);
    if(result==true){
      getData();
    }
  }

  void navigateToOrders(Coin coin) async{
    bool result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>CoinOrderList(coin)),);
    /*if(result==true){
      getOrderData();
    }*/
  }
}
```

And the output:
[image: output]

You can see I can display the output of data in the console.
But not in the text widget.
As it is stateful widget, I thought it would reflect the data.
And that too, I am setting/calling the function while creating the text field itself.

Comment: As long as you're working with a stateful widget, you have to call [setState](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) in order to update the UI

Comment: Hi there. You would have to post more code. Try posting the entire widget code as well as the implementation of the `getCurrentAssetsData` function. Provide proof of being able to print as well. since if you are able to print the data should be visible.

Comment: @Brugui Even if its a Stateful widget, OP is calling a function. Unless the function returns a Future, it shouldn't matter since he is not storing anything inside his state.

Comment: You're absolutely right, we'll need to see the function

Comment: I have added the function part, can you check now

Comment: Anf future object is involved in connecting DB.But my getCurrentAssetsData function is synchronous only

Comment: The problem here is that the `getCurrentAssetsData` function ends before the `coinOrderFuture` is resolved so you don't have the value on the listTile but because the `print` is inside the callback it prints the actual value when the future resolves.

Comment: Any alternative or wait can I keep to wait till the value appers here?I thought keeping in the then part would suffice, but it is not working right